# SwiftUI not being updated with manual publish

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject, observedobject

I have a class, a “clock face” with regular updates; it should display an array of metrics that change over time.

Because I’d like the clock to also be displayed in a widget, I’ve found that I had to put the class into a framework (perhaps there’s another way, but I’m too far down the road now). This appears to have caused a problem with SwiftUI and observable objects.

In my `View` I have:

```
@ObservedObject var clockFace: myClock
```

In the clock face I have:

```
class myClock: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: Int 
    @Publish public var metric:[metricObject] = []
    ....
    // at some point the array is mutated and the display updates
}
```

I don’t know if `Identifiable` is needed but it’s doesn’t make any difference to the outcome. The `public` is demanded by the compiler, but it’s always been like that anyway.

With these lines I get a runtime error as the app starts:

> objc[31175] no class for metaclass

So I took off the `@Published` and changed to a manual update:

```
public var metric:[metricObject] = [] {
    didSet {    
        self.objectWillChange.send()`
     }
}
```

And now I get a display and by setting a breakpoint I can see the `send()` is being called at regular intervals. But the display won’t update unless I add/remove from the array. I’m guessing the computed variables (which make up the bulk of the `metricObject` change isn’t being seen by SwiftUI. I’ve subsequently tried adding a “dummy” `Int` to the `myClock` class and setting that to a random value to trying to trigger a manual refresh via a `send()` on it’s `didSet` with no luck.

So how can I force a periodic redraw of the display?

Answer (score 2):

What is MetricObject and can you make it a `struct` so you get `Equatable` for free?

When I do this with an Int it works:

```
class PeriodicUpdater: ObservableObject {
  @Published var time = 0
  var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  init() {
    Timer
      .publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
      .autoconnect()
      .sink(receiveValue: { _ in
        self.time = self.time + 1
      })
      .store(in: &subscriptions)
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var updater = PeriodicUpdater()
  var body: some View {
    Text("\(self.updater.time)")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I’ll take a closer look at your code. Hopefully it’s just a simple case of using your`Timer` setup. The `metricObject` is a standard (?) class - nothing too complicated. I could make it a `struct`, it’s just if the act of having it all sit in a framework is causing the issue. But I can try that as well.

Comment: I can't use this code: the `@Published` causes a crash as outlined in the question.

Answer (score 0):

So it's taken a while but I've finally got it working. The problem seemed to be two-fold.

I had a class defined in my framework which controls the SwiftUI file. This class is sub-classed in both the main app and the widget.

Firstly I couldn't use `@Published` in the main class within the framework. That seemed to cause the error:

> objc[31175] no class for metaclass

So I used @JoshHomman's idea of an iVar that's periodically updated but that didn't quite work for me. With my SwiftUI file, I had:

```
struct FRMWRKShape: Shape {
  func drawShape(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    // draw and return a shape
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var updater = PeriodicUpdater()
  var body: some View {
    FRMWRKShape()
    //....
    FRMWRKShape() //slightly different parameters are passed in
  }
}
```

The `ContentView` was executed every second as I wanted, however the `FRMWRKShape` code was called but not executed(?!) - except on first starting up - so the view doesn't update. When I changed to something far less D.R.Y. such as:

```
struct ContentView: View {
 @ObservedObject var updater = PeriodicUpdater()
 var body: some View {
  Path { path in
          // same code as was in FRMWRKShape()
  }
        //....
  Path { path in
     // same code as was in FRMWRKShape()
     // but slightly different parameters
  }
 }
}
```

Magically, the `View` was updated as I wanted it to be. I don't know if this is expected behaviour, perhaps someone can say whether I should file a Radar....